# Check Array Entries with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an Array with one or more entries. Each one is a string (List of urls in open Tabs via Firefox SDK). I want to check if a specific url is already opened in some of the tabs (nothing special till now).

My problem is, that the url in tab list can have four diffrent fourms. For example:

Url I want to find in the tablist:

```
https://cmsr-author.de/cf#/content/test/de.html
```

But the url can also look like this:

```
https://cmsr-author.de/content/test/de.html
https://cmsr-author.de/test/de.html
https://cmsr-author.de/cf#/test/de.html
```

Of course the last part of the url (after /test/...) is always something diffrent. If I wasn't able to find one of the four urls in the tablist i want to call some other action.

My Solution till now is to build some if-chain:

```
if (res !== url1) {
  if (res !== url2) {
    if ...
```

But i thought there must be some more elegant way. Maybe via RegEx? I already have a capture to catch the first part (which stays the same https://cmsr-author.ws...) with it four forms. But i dont know how to implent this probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var urls = ["https://cmsr-author.de/content/test/de.html","https://cmsr-author.de/test/de.html","https://cmsr-author.de/cf#/test/de.html"]
var filtered = urls.filter(function(url) 
{ 
       return url.indexOf("cf#") > -1 && url.endsWith("/test/de.html")
})

var contains = filtered.length > 0
console.log(contains)
```

Comment: Seems like this will work if i catch the ending of the url bevor with a RegEx. (since the  ending will be always something diffrent for example .../test/ff/about/contact.html). But anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex you can do this by using groups for the middle part, which is explained in detail here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Practically, your regex would look something like that:

```
https:\/\/cmsr-author\.de\/(content|...|...)\/de\.html
```

Where ... must be replaced by the middle parts of the url which differ.
Note that | is "or" used to provide multiple possibilities within the group. The character / and . must be escaped since they have special roles in regex.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My English is not good,Do not fully understand what you mean,According to my idea,You should need a regular expression,Only to match the first.If I am wrong,
please @ me.

I hope that helps!

```js
var reg = /^https:\/\/cmsr\-author\.de\/cf#\/(?:\w+\/)+test\/de\.html$/gi;
var str1 = "https://cmsr-author.de/cf#/content/test/de.html";
var str2 = "https://cmsr-author.de/content/test/de.html";
var str3 = "https://cmsr-author.de/test/de.html";
var str4 = "https://cmsr-author.de/cf#/test/de.html";
console.log(reg.test(str1));
console.log(reg.test(str2));
console.log(reg.test(str3));
console.log(reg.test(str4));
```